# How to auto increment form option fields?

Tags: php

How can I increment the following in increments of 15min in php automatically?

```
<option value="9:00am" <?= ($item['starttime']) == '9:00am' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9:00am</option>
```

php output should look like this :

```
<option value="9:00am" <?= ($item['starttime']) == '9:00am' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9:00am</option>
<option value="9:15am" <?= ($item['starttime']) == '9:15am' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9:15am</option>
<option value="9:30am" <?= ($item['starttime']) == '9:30am' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9:30am</option>
etc, etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++)
{
$postfix = "am";
$k = $i;
if ($i >= 12)
    {
    $postfix = "pm";
    }

if ($i > 12) $k = $i - 12;
for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j+= 15)
    {
    $time = $k . ':' . str_pad($j, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . $postfix;
    $selected = "";
    if ($item['starttime'] == $time) $selected = "selected";
    echo '<option  value="' . $time . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $time . '</option>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved my am, pm issues, AND it is clear, concise, and easily understandable for a new programmer to utilize, modify.

Answer (score 1):

The one other way is :

```
// start time
$open_time = strtotime("9:00:00");
// end time
$close_time = strtotime("23:59:00");
// selected time
$item['starttime'] = '09:30:00am';
// increment by seconds 15 mins = 900secs
for( $i=$open_time; $i<$close_time; $i+=900) {
    $time = date("H:i:sa",$i);
    echo "<option value='$time'" .(($item['starttime'] == $time) ? ' selected' : '') .">$time</option>";
}
```

Please refer the below link for date formats
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: is there a way to convert that to where it shows as such : 8:00:00am, 8:00:00pm?

Comment: edited code. check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it :

```
<select>
<?php
$t = "09:00:00";                 // START TIME.
$item['starttime'] = "10:45:00"; // SELECTED TIME.
for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )    // DISPLAY 10 ITEMS.
{ $endTime = strtotime("+15 minutes", strtotime($t) ); // ADD 15 MINUTES.
  $t = date('h:i:s', $endTime);  // CONVERT TIME TO STRING.
  echo "<option value='$t' " .
       (($item['starttime'] == $t) ? 'selected' : '') .
       ">$t</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```